# Saving mysql into a file

Tags: mysql

I have tried the code suggestions to save MySQL output to a file, but none seem to work. The last one I used is this:

```
SELECT price FROM shop INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/abu/Desktop/pr.txt'
```

And it produced this:

> ->

Please tell me what is missing to get it done on Windows

Comment: You are probably missing a ; at the end of the statement (seems to be mysql cli)

Answer (score 0):

Table name **(shop)** will be declared at last.

```
SELECT price INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/abu/Desktop/pr.txt' FROM shop;
```

More options will be available with OUTFILE as mentioned in this [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-into-outfile/#example)

Comment: Thank you. I did what you suggested but I got this error message 'the MySQL server is running with the --secure -file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement. How can I solve that?

Comment: It's because mysql permits the path with "data" directory, so it causes the error to export/save data in external directory. you can use direct filename to store in permitted directory which is "C:\xampp\mysql\data\{databasename}".